# extending python using C extensions

Tags: python, c, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I am trying to learn how to extend python using C extensions and so far I have been able to go through the official python docs for the same.

Browsing through, I have found [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Extending_with_C#A_module_for_calculating_fibonacci_numbers) helpful resource which explains how to extend python using C extensions. So, the example looks like so:

```
#include <Python.h>

int
_fib(int n)
{
    if (n < 2)
        return n;
    else
        return _fib(n-1) + _fib(n-2);
}

static PyObject*
fib(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    int n;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &n))
        return NULL;

    return Py_BuildValue("i", _fib(n));
}

static PyMethodDef FibMethods[] = {
    {"fib", fib, METH_VARARGS, "Calculate the Fibonacci numbers."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
initfib(void)
{
    (void) Py_InitModule("fib", FibMethods);
}
```

However, I am having trouble in understanding what this piece of code does:

```
int
_fib(int n)
{
    if (n < 2)
        return n;
    else
        return _fib(n-1) + _fib(n-2);
}
```

especially, the `_` part of the function name.

I would really appreciate if someone could explain what the above piece of code does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply plain C code. The `_fib` function computes the nth [fibonacci number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

The `_` at the beginning of the name doesn't have any special meaning. It is *conventionally* (at least in the python community) used to denote "private" functions. They probably used `_fib` for the C function because they wanted to use `fib` for the wrapper.

I believe the example was meant to show how you could implement the core functionality as plain C, and add a wrapper to be accessed from python.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I quite new to C (as in, I have forgot most of it!) - but what does: `return _fib(n-1) + _fib(n-2);` exactly do here?

Comment: @JohnJ it's recursively computing the fibonacci sequence by calling itself over and over - https://www.khanacademy.org/science/computer-science-subject/computer-science/v/recursive-fibonacci-example

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: thanks so much. That clears it up for me. Accepted this answer!

Comment: @JohnJ Note that the given implementation of `_fib` is *extremely* slow (aka take exponential time with respect to `n`). There are many better ways to compute them, just search on the web if you don't know them already.

Comment: Thanks @Bakuriu for your tip. Fortunately I do not have a need to compute them - I was simply learning from the example. Thanks again for the heads up.